# Как записать значения в двумерный массив из файла?..

Tags: массивы, c++

Имеется двумерный массив типа double, в него нужно из файла записать числа, помогите с реализацией.

Comment: не проблема. 100$

Comment: @mikillskegg, фигасе цены, это же приказ

Comment: @Gorets, все нормально.

Comment: Если без шуток, то сразу встает вопрос: какова структура файла? Он текстовый или бинарный? Объем информации и размерность массива известны заранее или как-то записаны в файла? При написании программы использовать потоки или функции С? Пока не будет все уточнено, говорить не о чем.

Comment: Я набросал решение и хочу плюс!

Comment: @embarcadero, 100$

Comment: @embarcadero, как его поставить?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Пиши в текстовый файл элемент и после него ставь символ-разделитель, после последнего делай новую строку. И так далее.

**UPD 1.** Набросал код "за 100$" :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int n, m;
double **d;

void init()
{
    cin >> n >> m;
    d = new double*[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        d[i] = new double[m];
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << i << " " << j << " ";
            cin >> d[i][j];
        }
    }
}
void write()
{
    ofstream f("file.txt");
    f << n << endl << m << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            f << d[i][j] << endl;
}
void read()
{
    ifstream f("file.txt");
    f >> n >> m;
    cout << n << "  " << m << endl;
    d = new double*[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        d[i] = new double[m];
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            f >> d[i][j];
    }
    f.close();
}

int main()
{
    init();
    write();
    read();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            cout << d[i][j] << "  ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь, но код не работает) на экран выводится, что в массиве лежит не то, что в файле)

Comment: Я обновил код, приложил скриншот и написал это в Visual Studio 2010

Comment: У меня та же самая среда разработки, но экран теперь пустой) где должен лежать файл? в папке с проектом? а если он просто в корне диска с валяется, то путь к нему c:\\test.txt"?..

Comment: В данном случае файл создаётся сам, он будет лежать рядом с программой, в случае с запуском из среды - C:\Users\%name%\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Test\Test.
Возьми .exe файл из папки Debug, положи куда-нибудь и лицезрей файл. Код не кушает готовый, он делает каждый раз новый.

Comment: Не поняла вот... мне же надо, чтобы из файла заполнялись данные... откуда тогда будут данные поступать в массив?..

Comment: @embarcadero а смысл такого ответа?) плюсик в профиль?

Comment: http://zalil.ru/33455797
не умею заливать скрины...
в общем у меня загружаются какие то непонятные мне данные в массив... их нет в моем файле...

Comment: ну точнее они становятся в моем файле... но у меня задача то обратная... прочитать их файла данные... а не записать данные в файл...

Comment: У меня есть файл и я рядом лежит программа. В файле написано следующее: http://imagehost.spark-media.ru/i4/BE3F67C3-7D9D-3CF7-37E3-D7597F056CE2.jpg . 1 и 2 строки - это размерности массива, после - элементы. Как выглядит твой файл?

Comment: @Дарьялла, если в файле подряд лежат числа в том же порядке, что и в массиве - все из первой строки, потом все из второй и т.д., то все очень просто.

--

Делаете два вложенных цикла (внещний по строкам, внутренний по столбцам) и во внутреннем цикле читаете очередной элемент массива (например: 

    if (fscanf(f,"%ld",&a[j][j]) != 1) { puts("Беда"); exit(-1) }

или как Вам больше нравится.

По завершению циклов числа заполнят Ваш массив.